# Avoiding loop in a loop in a loop when building a WordPress custom sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a custom sitemap for a website I am working on, the only way I've managed to apply my custom filters and display the proper pages is to create several loops that check each time if the parent has children, then displays them accordingly. This is a fairly large site and has a ton of content.

This is my current loop which draws out each page title and link:

```
<?php $children = get_posts( array('category' => $region_id, 'post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => 100, 'post_parent' => $pg->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>

<?php if ($children) : ?>
    <ul class="children">
        <?php foreach ($children as $child) : ?>
            <?php $subkids = get_posts( array('category' => $region_id, 'post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => 100, 'post_parent' => $child->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($child->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $child->post_title;?>"><?php echo $child->post_title;?></a>
                <?php if( count( $subkids ) != 0 ) : ?>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <?php foreach($subkids as $kid) : ?>
                            <?php $subkids2 = get_posts( array('category' => $region_id, 'post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => 100, 'post_parent' => $kid->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($kid->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $kid->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $kid->post_title; ?></a>
                                <?php if( count( $subkids2 ) != 0 ) : ?>
                                    <ul class="children">
                                        <?php foreach($subkids2 as $kid2) : ?>
                                            <?php $subkids3 = get_posts( array('category' => $region_id, 'post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => 100, 'post_parent' => $kid2->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($kid2->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $kid2->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $kid2->post_title; ?></a>
                                                <?php if( count( $subkids3 ) != 0 ) : ?>
                                                    <ul class="children">
                                                        <?php foreach($subkids3 as $kid3) : ?>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($kid3->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $kid3->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $kid3->post_title; ?></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                <?php endif; //for if forth level children exist ($subkid3) ?>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; //for if third level children exist ($subkid2) ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; //for if second level children exist ($subkids) ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Edit: I removed my custom meta filters from the code to reduce space, but here is an example of what I apply inside each loop:

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta($child -> ID, 'wpcf-visible-in-sitemap'); ?>
<?php if($meta[0] != 1) : // If page should not be displayed, hide it ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($child -> ID); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($child -> ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($child -> ID); ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is really nasty looking, is there a more efficient way of coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions have resolved my issue, I was able to reduce the code to the following:

```
function check_for_children( $region_id, $children ) {
    if ( count($children) > 0 ) {
        echo '<ul class="children">';
        foreach($children as $child) {
            echo '<li>' . $child -> post_title . '</li>';
            $children = get_posts( array('category' => $region_id, 'post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => 100, 'post_parent' => $child -> ID, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') );
            check_for_children($region_id, $children);
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The function calls itself until there are no longer and children, at which point it moves along to the next set.